# Error while installing social plugin angularx-social-login in angular app

Tags: angular, visual-web-developer

Error while installing angular social login
npm install --save angularx-social-login

getting the following error
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a version conflict issue.

Make sure your Angular version is suitable to the package you're installing.

[image]

With that said, please notice that they are all deprecated, up to this date.

Here is a repository for Google Sign In with Angular and Google Identity:

https://github.com/ShemiNechmad/GoogleSignInAngular